# VBA Close workbooks except for previously opened

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've been trying to figure out a solution to this. So I have code in an excel workbook that opens and modifies embedded Sourcedata workbooks from charts in a word document.

What I want to do is close all the embedded workbooks from the charts in the word document, but using the Application.Workbooks collection and the 'For Each workbook' loop. When I tried to use this loop, it would close ALL the workbooks, even those that were open prior to running the code that opens up the embedded workbooks. So I made code that closes the embedded workbooks only like this but it takes too long:

```
 Dim K As InlineShape
    Dim chrt1 As Word.Chart
    Dim xWB As Workbook
     

 
For Each K In aktDocument.InlineShapes
           If K.HasChart Then
              Set chrt1 = K.Chart
              chrt1.ChartData.Activate
              Set xWB = chrt1.ChartData.Workbook
              xWB.Activate
             xWB.Close
           End If
    Next
```

Is there a way to use the For each workbook loop to close all the embedded workbooks and NOT close all other previously opened workbooks prior to running the code as well as ThisWorkbook (that contains code). The number of workbooks that are already open vary depending on the person running the code.

Comment: @Hafiz Oh okay thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing makes sense. Here is a version that uses `For...Next` instead of `For...Each`. I am also using nested `With` to automatically create and destroy objects as needed. Removing the `Activate` will speed things up a bit.

```
Public Sub CloseInlineExcelBooks()

    Dim thisShape As Long

    With ActiveDocument
        For thisShape = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
            With .InlineShapes(thisShape)
                If .HasChart Then
                    With .Chart.ChartData.Workbook
                        .Close
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next thisShape
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually sped up the code quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function to return the embedded workbooks name. Then you should iterate between the open workbooks and close them:

```
Function embededWB() As Variant
    Dim k As InlineShape, arr, k As Long
    
    ReDim arr(100)
    For Each k In aktDocument.InlineShapes
           If k.HasChart Then
              arr(k) = k.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Name: k = k + 1
           End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
    embededWB = arr
End Function
```

I would suggest the next way to use it:

```
 Sub testClosingWorkbooks()
  'part to create the open Excel object, let us say objExcel
  Dim objExcel As Object
  Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'open Excel session
  'if the Excel object is already referenced/created, you should use it...
  
  Dim arr, El, wb As Excel.Workbook
  For Each El In arr
     For Each wb In objExcel.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = El Then wb.Close
     Next wb
  Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try this.